# bs4 returns variable names but not content

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 in an attampt to retrieve weblinks to images from [the metropolitan](http://www.metmuseum.org/).

```
url = 'http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection#!?material=Canvas&showOnly=onDisplay&offset=1780&pageSize=0&sortBy=Relevance&sortOrder=asc&perPage=20'
soup =BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read().decode(),'html5lib').encode()
```

On the orginal webpage, the data i want looks like this, which holds the link that i want.

```
<figure class="card__standard-image">
        <a href="/art/collection/search/459087?sortBy=Relevance&amp;amp;what=Oil+paintings%7cPaintings&amp;amp;od=on&amp;amp;ft=*&amp;amp;offset=0&amp;amp;rpp=20&amp;amp;pos=1">
```

The data returned by bs4 looks like this:

```
<figure class="card__standard-image">\n        <a href="{{ card.url }}">
```

It seems to me that the link is replaced by card.url, but I don't know how to acces the values stored in card.

I have tried different parsers, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data you need is fetched by JavaScript, the read data is in this URL:

```
http://www.metmuseum.org/api/collection/collectionlisting?artist=&department=&era=&geolocation=&material=Canvas&offset=0&pageSize=0&perPage=20&showOnly=onDisplay&sortBy=Relevance&sortOrder=asc
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem for this instance. For the next time, how did you find/get to this url?